# PHP timeout when writing to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting a timeout when I execute the code below. Here's the exact error:

`Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\xampp\htdocs\logansarchive\admin\articlework.php on line 16
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\logansarchive\admin\articlework.php on line 0`

I feel that it is worth noting that between the time when this DID work and when it DIDN'T, nothing was changed on my web server or in this code.

Here's the code that does the work in the database:

```
<?php
    $action = $_REQUEST["action"];
    $target = $_REQUEST["target"];
    $srctitle = $_POST["srctitle"];
    $title = $_POST["article_title"];
    $cat = $_POST["article_cat"];
    $content = $_POST["article_content"];

    // Set database server access variables:
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $db = "logansarchive";

    // Open connection
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);   

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    switch ($action) {
        case "Edit":
            $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Articles ".
                "SET ArticleTitle = :title, Category = :cat, ArticleDate = :date, ArticleContent = :content ".
                "WHERE ArticleTitle = :srctitle");
            $query->bindParam(':title', $title);
            $query->bindParam(':cat', $cat);
            $query->bindParam(':date', $date);
            $query->bindParam(':content', $content);
            $query->bindParam(':srctitle', $srctitle);
            $query->execute();
        break;
        case "New":
            $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Articles(Category, ArticleDate, ArticleTitle, ArticleContent) ".
                "VALUES(:cat, :date, :title, :content)");
            $query->bindParam(':cat', $cat);
            $query->bindParam(':date', $date);
            $query->bindParam(':title', $title);
            $query->bindParam(':content', $content);
            $query->execute();
        break;
        case "Delete":
            if ($target != "") {
                $query = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Articles ".
                    "SET DeletedYN = :del ".
                    "WHERE ArticleTitle = :title");
                $query->bindValue(':del', "Yes");
                $query->bindParam(':title', $target);
                $query->execute();
            }
            else {
                header("Location: index.php?result=failed");
            }
        break;
    }

    header("Location: index.php?result=success");
?>
```

**EDIT 1:** I just realized something that may narrow down the cause of the problem.
The code above is the only part of the website where I'm using PDO. All the rest uses mysql_* and it all works fine. This leads me to believe that the problem lies with PDO.

Comment: It seems that PDO died at the connection stage.  Is the database overloaded, is it stuck in some other queries that consumed all its connection slots?  Have you double-checked the database's connection parameters?

Comment: log in into your mysql server via console and issue `show processlist;` command. If you see some connections with long lifetime probably your databse is overloaded. If there are some `Locked` connection, yuor database is in deadlock, try killing locked connections starting from the oldest one.

Comment: I don't think so it your code which cause the timeout, First of all you need to check why connection fails?

Comment: Do you have index on ArticleTitle? How many records do you have in the table?

Comment: @Sleepy @J0HN
There were only 2 processes returned by `show processlist;`. SLEEP and the show processlist; query.

Comment: @Treffynnon Thanks for mentioning that, it helps a lot </sarcasm>

Comment: @Darhazer the Articles table has PK ArticleID, not sure if that's the same as index. I've just started populating the table.

Comment: @LoganYoung My pleasure. No need for your invalid XML to denote the sarcasm in your response (it is dripping in the lowest form of wit all on it's own). Whilst I was tempted to help you out with the issue you are suffering I felt the desire ebb from me as I read your juvenile response. I wish you luck in finding a resolution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this bug: [MySQL functions cannot be used with 5.3.x on Vista when using "localhost"](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45150).  The timeout symptom is consistent with that bug.

The root cause seems to be that the MySQL server [doesn't support IPv6 until 5.5](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8836), but the default `hosts` file on modern Windows maps localhost to the IPv6 address `::1`.

So try setting `$host="127.0.0.1";`

I don't know why it's working with ext/mysql but failing with PDO.  That's a mystery.  Chalk it up to Windows making no sense in general anyway.  ;-)

Also see [PHP 5.3 and MySQL connectivity problem](http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2010/06/11/php-5-3-and-mysql-connectivity-problem.aspx) for more explanation of the IPv6 issue.

Comment: Haha thanks for that Bill, it had been pointed out to me by someone online, I just wasn't allowed to answer my own question within 8 hours. Nevertheless, +1 and answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I finaly solved it.

The thing is, I had a "new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb','myuser', 'my pass');" into a for/while loop.

When I do 3 or 4 loops it is all right. When I have 5000 iterations, my mySQL server seems to block me and then I get the "Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] 'A connection attempt fail..." error message.

I know this wasn't too clever to put a "new PDO(..." into a loop. Hope this will help you guys.

antoine